# XML and XSL format linking

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Hi Im having trouble linking my XML and XSLT, My XML is long but heres a extract, The problem is my XSLT is not formatting it, I am trying to get my XML displayed under each other with a title. forgive me but english is not my first language

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Product_List.xsl"?>
<ProductCatalogue>
    <drinks>
        <product>
            <name Product_Code="D001">Lemonade</name>
            <price>6.50</price>
            <amount>20</amount>
            <supplier>Coca-Cola</supplier>
        </product>
    </drinks>
</ProductCatalogue>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h3>Product List</h3>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="drinks">
    <div style="color:#0000FF">
        <h3>
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div>
        <xsl:value-of select="name@Product_code"/>
    </div>
    <p>Price : <xsl:value-of select="price"/></p>
    <p>Supplier : <xsl:value-of select="supplier"/></p>
    <p>Amount : <xsl:value-of select="amount"/></p>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I believe its a problem with my templates but im not sure how its fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe its a problem with my templates but im not sure how its fixed

Yes, there is indeed a problem with your templates. The easiest way to make your transformation actually output the values is to change the second template match, originally

```
<xsl:template match="drinks">
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="product">
```

Inside this template, you are selecting elements like `name` and `price`, which are child elements of `product`, not of `drinks`.

Also, change

```
<xsl:value-of select="name@Product_code"/>
```

to

```
<xsl:value-of select="name/@Product_Code"/>
```

XML and all the technologies related to it are *case-sensitive* - `Product_code` is not the same as `Product_Code`.

Then, the output will be

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h3>Product List</h3>


      <div style="color:#0000FF">
         <h3>Lemonade</h3>
      </div>
      <div>D001</div>
      <p>Price : 6.50</p>
      <p>Supplier : Coca-Cola</p>
      <p>Amount : 20</p>


   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you based god, you fixed my problem

Comment: @user3636602 You are welcome. I can assure you I'm not a god though.